# How to fit a Gaussian into my data (csv) file using Python

Tags: python, gaussian, lmfit

I have collated the data and have it in CSV.format. I wish to fit a Gaussian into my data using Python. Can someone help me with the starting steps?
I have gone through the lmfit. documentation from Python. I'm not very sure how to go about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fitting a Gaussian is as simple as calculating the mean and the standard deviation of your data:

```
import numpy as np

data = <load data here>

mu = np.mean(data)
sigma = np.std(data, ddof=1)
```

Here, `mu` and `sigma` are the two parameters of the Gaussian.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response!. I wish to view my data points and the bell curve as well? Could you help me with this regard?

Comment: @AngelaMary, you can use [Matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org) to visualize data in Python

Answer (score 1):

you say you read the `lmfit` documentation. It pretty much explains how to accomplish this with the `lmfit` package; what is not clear about the description [here](https://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/builtin_models.html#example-1-fit-peak-data-to-gaussian-lorentzian-and-voigt-profiles) or this [example](https://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/examples/documentation/model_gaussian.html#sphx-glr-examples-documentation-model-gaussian-py)?

You should be able to adapt these to your specific situation. If you have trouble doing that you'll have to provide a "minimal, working example" of your code and/or explain *what* is not working.